# Access vhost config website in another PC

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, vhosts

may I ask question about the Apache Virtual Host config?

**I use XAMPP, my develop app is Wordpress.**

I have configured my host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc...) like

```
127.0.0.1 tommydo.dev
127.0.0.1 172.25.129.113/tommydo.dev <== *172.25.129.113 is my local PC's IP address*
```

and C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra**httpd-vhosts.conf** like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/tommydo.dev"
    ServerName tommydo.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

It was successful when I access from my PC (LAN). With URL: http://tommydo.dev

But when I access from another computer using http://172.25.129.113/tommydo.dev is was broken. Of course ! Because of my Wordpress config is "tommydo.dev" only.

My question is: Is it possible to configure or access from another PC to my WP in localhost in my own PC?

Comment: You can either put an entry in the DNS or modify the host file at each PC to point to your ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get [Apache to listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#page-header) to `172.25.129.113` on port `80`. Use the following to listen to Port 80 on all interfaces

   > Listen 80
2. On the other computer try going to http://172.25.129.113
3. You could end up with 404 errors with the path http://tommydo.dev.
   This could be solved by

   - Reconfiguring the site to use http://172.25.129.113
   - Adding the below to each Computer's hosts file

     > 172.25.129.113                  tommydo.dev
   - Setup a DNS system in your LAN to have *tommydo.dev* as a Domain Name.

---

Also

> 127.0.0.1 172.25.129.113/tommydo.dev

is invalid because the second part is [not a hostname](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts)

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer and sorry about late replying. I work it in my company, I cannot control the DNS server so..... Anyway, best thanks, I will try it in my home local and report for you guy about the result.